# python 3d cube to 2d gif

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there an obvious way to make a gif from a `(20, 455, 500)` cube? So 20 images of 455x500.

Plotting one is easy, but what does one do if you want to see all of them? I'm guessing that I am missing the right keyword, as googling this did not give a solution. But I can't imagine that nobody did this before.

```
plt.imshow(cube_array[0])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you mean an [animation](https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_anim.html)?

Comment: That is probably it! but how does one do this if you have an array and are not repotting the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example for creating a matplotlib animation
from 3d data cube.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

cube_array = np.random.rand(20, 455, 500)

fig = plt.figure()
img = plt.imshow(cube_array[0], animated=True)

def updatefig(i):
    img.set_array(cube_array[i])
    return img,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, frames=cube_array.shape[0],
                              interval=25, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Sources:

https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/dynamic_image.html
https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html